# referring a string from one collection to another collection (mongoose schema)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to know how to refer a String from one collection to another collection?
I have a model which goes like this.

```
const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
address: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Now my need has changed, instead of `projectId` I need to refer to projectName
which is a string, for last 5 hrs, i tried all these possible methods, it ain't working, somebody guide me in right direction.

```
const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
projectName: { type: String, ref: 'Project', required: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
address: { type: String, required: true }
    });
```

and also I tried this line also,

```
projectName: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Project', required: true }
```

Well i m trying to this query:

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
Project.findOneAndUpdate({projectName:projectName}, 
       { $push: { enrichedEvents: enrichedEventId}},
            function (error, success) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(success);
                }
            });

const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    projectName: req.body.projectName, 
});
return enrichedEvent.save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Event stored",
            createdEvent: {
                _id: result._id,
                project: result.project,
                name: result.name,

            },
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `projectName: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true }`  take it as `objectId`

Comment: will try and update you...

Comment: not working buddy!!!

Comment: what is the error... which query you are running?

Comment: @ashish updated the question, Please check it.

Comment: totally wrong approach... 

you should refer first how to create schema in mongoose https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/

Comment: I have followed the same article only...

Comment: The error i am getting is `{"error":{"message":"projectName is not defined"}}`

Comment: `Project.findOneAndUpdate({projectName:projectName}` from where this `projectName` comes?

Comment: Just pass `req.body.proejctName` in update query

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi Thanks!!!  that solved my problem

Comment: @darshanan You are welcome, can you please upvote the comment.